# Elements are not displayed on the pane inside a pane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am writing a vector canvas in JavaFX (vector graphics, just shapes are displayed on the canvas): well, so that you can move around and zoom in on it.

Since the position of the upper-left corner of the node changes when translating, and it no longer responds to clicks, I decided to make a panel inside the canvas itself, on which everything will be displayed.

Inside the `VectorCanvas` there is a `VectorCanvasContent`.
Lines are added to `VectorCanvasContent`, but for some reason they are not visible (although they are there, I added a listener that outputs "!!!" when you click on them, and checked).
If I draw lines on the canvas itself, then they are visible.

What is the problem?

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class VectorCanvas extends Pane {

    public class VectorCanvasContent extends Pane {
        public static final Consumer<VectorCanvas> DEFAULT_DRAWER = canvas -> {
            Line[] lines = {
                    new Line(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 0),
                    new Line(canvas.getWidth(), 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()),
                    new Line(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 0, canvas.getHeight()),
                    new Line(0, canvas.getHeight(), 0, 0),
                    new Line(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()),
                    new Line(0, canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), 0)
            };
            for (Line line : lines) {
                line.setStrokeWidth(30);
                line.setStroke(Color.RED);
                line.setFill(Color.RED);
                line.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> System.out.println("!!!"));
            }
            canvas.drawAll(lines);
        };
    }

    private final Consumer<VectorCanvas> drawer;

    public final VectorCanvasContent content = new VectorCanvasContent();

    public VectorCanvas() {
        this(VectorCanvasContent.DEFAULT_DRAWER);
    }

    public VectorCanvas(Consumer<VectorCanvas> drawer) {
        this.drawer = drawer;
        getRealChildren().add(content);
        draw();
    }

    public void clear() {
        getChildren().clear();
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (drawer != null)
            drawer.accept(this);
    }

    public void redraw() {
        clear();
        draw();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
        return content.getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Node> getChildrenUnmodifiable() {
        return content.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    }

    private ObservableList<Node> getRealChildren() {
        return super.getChildren();
    }

    private ObservableList<Node> getRealChildrenUnmodifiable() {
        return super.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    }

    public void draw(Shape shape) {
        getChildren().add(shape);
    }

    public void drawAll(Shape... shapes) {
        getChildren().addAll(shapes);
    }
}
```

Comment: The nomenclature used here is confusing.  In the JavaFX parlance, a [Canvas](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) is for drawing [raster graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) using a [GraphicsContext](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html), not vectors. If you aren't using a Canvas, then I don't advise using Canvas in any of your names, else you confuse everybody involved.

Comment: "Since the position of the upper-left corner of the node changes when translating, and it no longer responds to clicks" -> I don't agree with this, a translated node can still react to clicks.

Comment: @jewelsea yeah, a translated node can react to clicks, but it won't react at the previous position. For example: if we have a button at position (0, 0) and translate it by (10, 10) a click on (5, 5) won't trigger a mouse event. And for a canvas it is necessary.

Comment: oh ok, what you state is correct, if you translate something and if you then then click at the original location, it is no longer there, so it will not accept a click at that original location.  That is kind of a strange requirement, but I accept that is what you want, though I don't understand why, perhaps understanding why isn't necessary to help solve your issue.

Comment: @jewelsea it's not difficult for me to explain: on my canvas I want to draw some shapes. And I want to be able to draw shapes in negative positions. And I want to be able to move my canvas (change camera x and y). That's why I need to register clicks when translating the canvas (moving the camera).

Comment: Note that JavaFX has a [translatable camera](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Camera.html) you could translate that to move the camera rather than translating a node, but I am not sure if that is a good idea for you or not (it may well not be).

Comment: @jewelsea I removed the override and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @jewelsea and about camera. It is related to Scene. As I understood, I can't use it to create such a canvas that I want.
Do you have any ideas how to create one? At the moment I see no other solution rather than a pane inside a pane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246288/discussion-between-jewelsea-and-name-surname).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not override `getChildren()` and `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` to return the children of a different node (especially a contained node).

That may confuse and break the JavaFX layout system because it would be something quite unexpected for it.